# Missing request method, remote address and status code

Tags: javascript, jquery, request-headers

In my application (HTML, JavaScript), I am calling a simple GET API (HTTPS). I have noticed in chrome dev tool that sometimes when the call fails, the request method, remote address, and status code are missing. What may be the possible cause for this? Anything related to the network where the app is running?

[image]

Comment: What is displayed in the Network table? Especially in the Status column? It must give an explanation of the failure.

Comment: No explanation. Just "Failed to load response data". Also, there is no response header.

Comment: Seems like it's either connectivity or server problem.

Comment: What kind of server problem? Any specific area where I can focus? Note: The same code works fine on hundreds of other devices and even more than 10 devices in the same network.

Comment: Sorry I can't advice anything more specific because this error is too general. If it's connectivity problem then something is wrong with your network, for example bad signal. If it's a server problem then you need to investigate server logs.